# Project Template in vs 2010 - How to display a project template in hierarchy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, project

I created a project template.

I interested to display the project template in hierarchy like this:
MyCompany --> Web --> MyProjectTempalte
for this I changed the file MyTemplate.vstemplate:

MyCompany
Web

But this not affected on the hierarchy 
and the project template displayed under: `C# --> Web`

How I gets the hierarchy ?

MyTemplate:
    
      
        BLLControlsWebFormsApp
        A project for creating a .. application with a web user interface
        MyCompany
        Web
        
        1000
        true
        BLLControlsWebFormsApp
        true
        Enabled
        true
        _*TemplateIcon.ico*
        _PreviewImage.png
      
      
        
          
          Global.asax
          Global.asax.cs
          Instruction.txt
          
            BreadCrumbs.aspx
            BreadCrumbs.aspx.cs
            BreadCrumbs.aspx.designer.cs
            SubHeader.aspx
            SubHeader.aspx.cs
            SubHeader.aspx.designer.cs
            TabStrip.aspx
            TabStrip.aspx.cs
            TabStrip.aspx.designer.cs
          
          
            AssemblyInfo.cs
          
          
            
              
            
            
              jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js
              jquery-1.4.1.js
              jquery-1.4.1.min.js
            
            
              masterPage.css
            
          
          Site.Master
          Site.Master.cs
          Site.Master.designer.cs
          Web.config
          Web.Debug.config
          Web.Release.config

Comment: can you show us the vstemplate file?

Comment: I could not copy the contents normal, so I added a picture of the content

Comment: please use the "code" tool in the question editor to put the code. To be simple, add 4 spaces before each line of code. Read [ask] page for more info